# Onblur returns wrong data

Tags: javascript

My form check does not work. If I leave alias field empty it returns name field as filled.

```
var alias = document.getElementById("alias");
var name = document.getElementById("name");
var status = '';

function checkIt() {
    if (alias.value != '') {
        document.getElementById("alias").style.borderColor = "#3c763d";
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("alias").style.borderColor = "#a94442";
        status = false;
    }
    if (name.value != '') {
        document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor = "#3c763d";
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor = "#a94442";
        status = false;
    }
}

name.onblur=checkIt;
alias.onblur=checkIt;
```

Comment: are you allowed/familiar using JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you should use current object `this` instead of global variable when eventing firing

```
var alias = document.getElementById("alias");
var name = document.getElementById("name");
var status = '';

function checkIt() {
if (this.value != '') {
    this.style.borderColor = "#3c763d";
    status = true;
} else {
    this.style.borderColor = "#a94442";
    status = false;
}
}

name.onblur=checkIt;
alias.onblur=checkIt;
```

[<kbd>**JSFIDDLE DEMO**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/vTE3u/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

***Plain Js***

> script

```
var validate = function(e) {
    var v = this.value;
    this.style.borderColor = ('' !== v) ? '#3c763d' : '#a94442';
};

document.getElementById('alias').onblur = validate;
document.getElementById('name').onblur = validate;
```

***JQuery***

> script

```
$(function(){
    $("#alias, #name").on('focusout', function() {
        var box = $(this);
        var c = ('' !== box.val()) ? '#3c763d' : '#a94442';
        box.css('border-color', c);
    });
})
```